# Using universal image loader but image getting loaded only once

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, server, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to make an app that has 2 buttons. Using OPEN CAMERA we take a picture using camera intent and convert it to base64 encoding and store it on server.
Using GET PICTURE we try to get the picture from the server and display it in an imageview using universalimageloader .
The first part,ie, storing the picture is working perfectly but I'm not able to download the image and display it in the imageview.

```
    package backbenchersbeta.task;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming.Md5FileNameGenerator;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.QueueProcessingType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.WeakMemoryCache;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageAware;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageViewAware;


import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static int TAKE_PIC =1;
    Uri outPutfileUri;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;



        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext())
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                    .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    }
    public void CameraClick(View v) {

        Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

        outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
        params.put("filename", "temp.jpg");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Taking pic",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);



    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PIC && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Toast.makeText(this, outPutfileUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                prgDialog.setMessage("Converting Image to Binary Data");
                prgDialog.show();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started converting",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
            byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
            prgDialog.setMessage("Calling Upload");
            params.put("image", ba1);

            triggerImageUpload();} catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    public void triggerImageUpload() {
        makeHTTPCall();
    }

    public void makeHTTPCall() {
        prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking Php");
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        // Don't forget to change the IP address to your LAN address. Port no as well.
        client.post("http://192.168.43.145:80/imgupload/upload_image.php",
                params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code '200'
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code other than '200' such as '404',
                    // '500' or '403' etc
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {

                        prgDialog.hide();
                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Requested resource not found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code is '500'
                        else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Something went wrong at server end",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error Occured n Most Common Error: n1. Device not connected to Internetn2. Web App is not deployed in App servern3. App server is not running HTTP Status code : "
                                            + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void GetPicture(View v) {
        String url="http://192.168.43.145:80/imgupload/uploadedimages/temp.jpg";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside getpic",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .build();
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(img, false);

        imageLoader.displayImage(url,img,options);
        /*Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(
            "http://192.168.43.145:80/imgupload/uploadedimages/temp.jpg");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/
    }
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException
    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside imputstream",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside tryblock1",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside tryblock2",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            httpConn.connect();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside tryblock3",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }
    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

         // ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);

                ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);
            config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
                config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
                config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());

                config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
                config.writeDebugLogs(); // Remove for release app


                // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
            }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside dowmloadimage",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        // Dismiss the progress bar when application is closed
        if (prgDialog != null) {
            prgDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

The layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="backbenchersbeta.task.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Open Camera"
        android:onClick="CameraClick"
        android:background="#0054a6"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Get Picture"
        android:onClick="GetPicture"
        android:background="#0054a6"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that although the image is getting displayed once but after taking another picture it's not getting changed even after clicking get picture.

Comment: debug can be done more efficiently using Debug in IDE, add break points and inspect the code and outputs, meanwhile, why don't you try to use universal image loader it's a good library.

Comment: i'm exploring the library. I've also added 2 new toasts and found that httpConn.connect(); is not working..could you please look into it

Comment: Does it display "Inside getpic" ?

Comment: yes it displays that

Comment: not so sure, but what happens if you try this `HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();` and comment out the `if instance oh http...`

Comment: and comment out `httpConn .connect()`

Comment: @Yazan I'm now using universal image loader and it's working fine but only once. After taking another picture it's not loading the new picture. Can you please look into it. I'm posting the edit

Answer (score 0):

In GetPicture I made the following changes

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(false) .cacheOnDisc(false).resetViewBeforeLoading(true).build();
```

The problem occurred because the image stored in cache was being displayed.